# Save the values in array (and override for each update)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm having the trouble with saving the values as array.

I have such HTML code:

```
<div id="cn1" class="container cont container4">  
<input id="slider1" type="range" class="slider slider1" min="0" max="5" value="1" step="1">
<input id="slider2" type="range" class="slider slider2" min="0" max="5" value="1" step="1">
<input id="slider3" type="range" class="slider slider3" min="0" max="5" value="1" step="1">
<input id="slider4" type="range" class="slider slider4" min="0" max="5" value="1" step="1">
<input id="slider5" type="range" class="slider slider5" min="0" max="5" value="1" step="1"></div>
```

5 containers with 5 sliders inside = 25 sliders.

Need to get the id and values for each sliders and save as

```
 "sliders":[
               {
                    "slider":"slider1",
                    "value":"1"
               },
               { 
                     "slider":"slider2", 
                     "value":"1"
                }...
       ]
```

Here is the script to get the values for each slider:

```
 slider = $('.slider');
 var len = slider.length;

 $(slider).change(function () {
     bt = $(this).attr('id');
      value = $(this).val();

      save = '{"slider":"' + bt + '", "value":"' + value + '"}';
         console.log('save', save);
      })

     .trigger('change');
 }
```

So, i see in console 'save' for each slider.

I need to write each 'save' as array of values, then this data with be saved in json file and used for the other page.

I'm trying

```
function saveValues(){

     var toSave = '"slide10" : {';

     toSave += '"sliders":[';

     for (var i=1;i<len;i++) {
         toSave +=''+save+',';
     }

     toSave+=']';
     return toSave+='}';
}
```

But it save the value for the last 'save' 25 times... :( Like this:

```
"sliders":[
               {
                    "slider":"slider25",
                    "value":"1"
               },
               { 
                     "slider":"slider25", 
                     "value":"1"
                }...
       ]
```

How can I save the values in array (and override for each change of the value of corresponding slider)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
//get all range type's
var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('[type="range"]');
//prepare array variable
var result = [];
//loop the sliders
for(var i=0, l=sliders.length; i < l; i++){
    var slider = sliders[i];
    //push the object with id and value in the array
    result.push({
        slider: slider.id,
        value: slider.value
    });
}
//display the result :)
console.log(result);
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWKSv/1/)

Comment: You forgot the update part, where he needs to change the value in case the slider changes

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot! But could you please help be a bit more? :(

Comment: @SamLewis What you need to do is first create the object in javascript and not create it by string. After you created your object or array you can use `JSON.stringify` to turn your object to a string.